# Scala: how to set an actor thread name

Tags: scala, akka

When defining an Actor class I can't see any obvious way to set the thread name.

Can anyone tell me what the correct way to do it would be?

Thanks
Des

Comment: I am not referring to the Akka Actor class but rather the scala Actor class which although based on the Akka library is not the same if I understand it correctly? The reason I was asking is that I want to set the thread name is for debugging purposes in order to clarify the relevant thread in the log files

Comment: `scala.actors` is deprecated and bears no relation to Akka actors.

Comment: So should I rather be using the Akka actors library in that case?

Comment: If you're starting from scratch, absolutely.  If not, here's a [migration guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html)

Comment: @user79074 absolutely, the choice of deprecating Scala Actors in favour of Akka is a de facto endorsement, nowadays the synonym of message passing semantics in Scala is Akka, just go for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka Actors are not equivalent to threads, even if their code is being executed in a pool of threads, if you refer to the actor name you can set it by (from [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html)):

```
class FirstActor extends Actor {
  val child = context.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "myChild")
  // plus some behavior ...
}
```

Every actor has simply a path that you can query to obtain an ActorRef, which is a proxy to the real actor.
If you need further information about actor references and paths you can read another part of the [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html).

Comment: If you create your own ExecutionContext, then you can probably give the threads in it any names you'd like, but you'll still have problems of fluid actor->thread mapping unless you pin them all in such a way as to defeat many of the benefits.

Comment: @RobStarling yeas I think Akka has these kinds of hooks, but I thought there was already too much for the OP to read! :)